# Quartz.net keeping a single Scheduler running asp.net

Tags: asp.net, quartz.net

Am I understanding this correctly?

```
ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
IScheduler sched = sf.GetScheduler();
    sched.Start();
```

Is the StdSchedulerFactory a singleton?

What I want to achieve is in my global,asax on Application_Start to start up the quartz scheduler, and then later on in one of my classes create the job, the trigger, get a handle again to the scheduler, and schedule the job/trigger

But as it turns out, I need to re-start the scheduler, I thought it was already started?

Or is there now more than 1 scheduler running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical scenarios when embedding the scheduler in ASP.Net are to:

1. Create your scheduler as a singleton and then access it using something like Scheduler.Instance.
2. If you use DI, have the container give you a reference to the (singleton and already started) scheduler.
3. Use a global variable and have it reference the started scheduler.