# Quartz.NET trigger does not fire, MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, quartz.net

I have a MVC4 .Net web application on 3-tier architecture with Unity dependency injection, and I want to shedule everyday a verficiation and send some mails where is the case. For this I want to use Quartz Scheduler in Application_start, because of the dependency injection windows service is not a good option.

Here is my code in application_start.

```
        // construct a scheduler factory
        ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();
        sched.Start();

        IJobDetail dailyUserMailJob = new JobDetailImpl("DailyUserMailJob", null, typeof(SchedulerJob));
        // fire every time I open App/EveryDay
        ITrigger dailyUserMailTrigger = new SimpleTriggerImpl("DailyUserMailTrigger", 1,
                                                 new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0));
        sched.ScheduleJob(dailyUserMailJob, dailyUserMailTrigger);
```

Here is my job code :

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using EvaluationMvc.Bll.Contracts;
 using Quartz;
 using Quartz.Impl;

namespace EvaluationMvc.Utils
{
   public class SchedulerJob : IJob
   { 
      private IEvaluationBus _iEvaluationBus;

      public SchedulerJob(IEvaluationBus iEvaluationBus)
      {
        //Dependency injection
          _iEvaluationBus = iEvaluationBus; 

      }
      public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
      {
        _iEvaluationBus.testingArchitecture();
       // Sends a test mail.
      }
  }
}
```

However my job is never executed, what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quartz.net Scheduler must be created as [singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10132534/219406).

You can install [Unity.MVC4](http://nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc4/) NuGet Package.
It will create a **Bootstrapper** class which should look something like this:

```
public static class Bootstrapper
{
    public static IUnityContainer Initialise()
    {
        var container = BuildUnityContainer();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
        return container;
    }

    private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        // Register your interfaces here. 
        RegisterTypes(container);
        return container;
    }

    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
    }
}
```

Then you have to create your own implementation of **JobFactory**. This [article](http://blog.goyello.com/2009/09/21/how-to-use-quartz-net-in-pro-way/) might help you and [this one](http://jayvilalta.com/blog/2012/07/02/quartz-net-ijobfactory-interface/) is worth reading:

```
public class UnityJobFactory: IJobFactory
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer container;

    static UnityJobFactory()
    {
    }

    public UnityJobFactory(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        var jobDetail = bundle.JobDetail;
        var jobType = jobDetail.JobType;

        try
        {
            return this.container.Resolve(jobType) as IJob;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new SchedulerException(string.Format(
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                "Cannot instantiate class '{0}'", new object[] { jobDetail.JobType.FullName }), ex);
        }
    }

    public void ReturnJob(IJob job)
    {
        // Nothing here. Unity does not maintain a handle to container created instances.
    }
}
```

and your own implementation of **StdSchedulerFactory**:

```
public class UnitySchedulerFactory : StdSchedulerFactory
{
    private readonly UnityJobFactory unityJobFactory;

    public UnitySchedulerFactory(UnityJobFactory unityJobFactory)
    {
        this.unityJobFactory = unityJobFactory;
    }

    protected override IScheduler Instantiate(QuartzSchedulerResources rsrcs, QuartzScheduler qs)
    {
        qs.JobFactory = this.unityJobFactory;
        return base.Instantiate(rsrcs, qs);
    }
}
```

Going back to your **Unity Bootstrapper** you have to register your interfaces:

```
    private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<ISchedulerFactory, UnitySchedulerFactory>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IScheduler>(new InjectionFactory(c => c.Resolve<ISchedulerFactory>().GetScheduler()));
        container.RegisterType<IQuartzScheduler, QuartzScheduler>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IEvaluationBus, EvaluationBus>();

        RegisterTypes(container);

        return container;
    }
```

I've wrapped up my service scheduler in a class so that I can create it singleton:

```
public interface IQuartzScheduler
{
    void Run();
    void Stop();
}
```

and:

```
public class QuartzScheduler : IQuartzScheduler
{
    private readonly ISchedulerFactory SchedulerFactory;
    private readonly IScheduler Scheduler;

    public QuartzScheduler(ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        this.SchedulerFactory = schedulerFactory;
        this.Scheduler = scheduler;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        IJobDetail dailyUserMailJob = new JobDetailImpl("DailyUserMailJob", null, typeof(Scheduler.SchedulerJob));
        // fire every time I open App/EveryDay
        ITrigger dailyUserMailTrigger = new SimpleTriggerImpl("DailyUserMailTrigger", 10,
                                                 new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 20));

        this.Scheduler.ScheduleJob(dailyUserMailJob, dailyUserMailTrigger);

        this.Scheduler.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        this.Scheduler.Shutdown(false);
    }
}
```

As you can see in this class I'll create my jobs/trigger and start the scheduler.

now in your **Application_Start** (global.asax) you can "bootstrap" your Unity Container, get the service scheduler and run it.

```
var unityContainer = Infrastructure.Bootstrapper.Initialise();
unityContainer.Resolve<IQuartzScheduler>().Run();
```

You can find a working sample following this [link](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=669ADF1AF64DF389!238&authkey=!AHFO6dkSHJKiIHc) (**QuartzWithUnity**).

Answer (score 0):

Very useful, thanks LeftyX. I think, in Application_Start you have to create servise like this:

```
var unityContainer = Bootstrapper.Initialise();
QuartzScheduler jobService = (QuartzScheduler)unityContainer.Resolve(typeof(QuartzScheduler), "Jobs");
jobService.Run();
```